# Last y-axis tick gridline not showing with chart title displayed

Tags: javascript, chart.js, gridlines

I'm making a stacked bar graph using Chart.js, with (total stacked) values ranging from 0 to 1 (displayed as 0-100%). I'd like to have a tick/gridline displayed every 0.20/20%, from 0 to and including 1/100%.

Right now, my chart will display the last gridline at 1/100% if I don't include a graph title, but will hide the gridline (but still have the tick label) if I display the title.

Any tips to get the gridline to show?

JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/amyzlc/n99xac76/, and relevant graph code below.

Link to image of graph with title and without top gridline [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ1b0.png).

```
var stackedBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataChart,
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true, //top gridline displays if false, not if true
            text: 'Month-wise Adherence'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },              
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {display: false}
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {drawBorder: false, tickMarkLength: 3},
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1, //not showing with title
                    padding: 6,
                    stepSize: 0.2,
                    callback: function(value) {
                        return Math.round(value*100).toString() + "%";
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!